# How to get value from specific cell from a HTML table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I've got a table looking like this (AngularJS):

```
<tr id="table">
    <td style="text-align: center">{{flight.FlightFrom}}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">{{flight.FlightTo}}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">{{flight.Departure}}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">{{flight.Arrival}}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">{{flight.Price | currency: "PLN "}}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center" id="sits">{{flight.AvailableSits}}</td>
    <td><button type="button" id="buttonBuy">Kup bilet!</button></td>
</tr>
```

And I want to get to the `{{flight.AvailableSits}}` value, to check if its equal to 0, and if it is, then I want to disable the Buy button. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td><button type="button" id="buttonBuy" ng-disabled="flight.AvailableSits === 0">Kup bilet!</button></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ng-show` directive on the button.

```
<button type="button" id="buttonBuy" ng-show="flight.AvailableSits">Kup bilet!</button>
```

This will show the button only when there are available seats